# Adding Column to CSV file and Filling with Correct Data

Tags: powershell

Currently I'm pulling the location of my asset from a database, and I'm able to get the location from the database and store it in a variable. The issue I'm having now is adding just the correct field for the asset, instead of it putting all the locations in each row.

```
$List2 = foreach ($m in $MainList.'System Name') {
    Get-MdbcData (New-MdbcQuery Asset -eq $m)
}
$Business = $List2.Location
$overlist = $MainList |
            Select-Object 'System Name', @{Name='Name';Expression={$Business}}
```

I just hope to have it so for each asset, that the correct location is placed in a new column, and have the correct data in each row. That instead of how it's putting all the results in the one cell, and doing it for every row in it's column.

Comment: `@{Name='Name';Expression={$Business}}` -> `@{Name='Name';Expression={(Get-MdbcData (New-MdbcQuery Asset -eq $_.'System Name')).Location}}`

Comment: You're awesome, that worked great!